# Linq query for referal manager

Tags: c#, linq

I have a requirement in my LINQ in MVC application  i.e. I need to populate the list of employeeId in  a dropdown, to assign mgr to employee's, whose are not subordinate of his or his subordinates subordinate. To make my point more clear below is the scenario-

```
Id  MgrId
1 
2    1   
3    
4    2  
5
6    3
```

I try

```
empBO.GetAllEmpList().Where(s => s.Id != model.ID && s.MgrId != model.ID);
```

this works for only one level, from the above when I select empid 1 for edit to assign the mgr the drop down should only contain empid of 3,5 and  6. I haven't had much expertise in LINQ and hopt this could be done using LINQ any suggestion/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive method to find all subordinates of given employee (note, if hierarchy depth is big, you can use [query/stack implementation](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/04/Replacing_Recursion_With_a_Stack.aspx/) instead of recursion):

```
public static IEnumerable<Employee> GetSubordinates(
    IEnumerable<Employee> employees, int employeeId)
{
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        if (employee.MgrId != employeeId)
            continue;

        yield return employee;

        foreach (var subordinate in GetSubordinates(employees, employee.Id))
            yield return subordinate;
    }
}
```

Getting available employees will be simple:

```
var employees = GetAllEmpList();
var available = employees.Except(GetSubordinates(employees, selectedId));
```

This method will return employees with ids { 2, 4 }. Then calling [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will give you all employees besides those who are direct or indirect subordinated of selected one.

Comment: Thanks Sergey for your prompt response and appreciate your suggestion. I tried this but it's in reserves to what I expected i.e. I expected the empids of all employee other then the subordinate but in this case it fetches the subordinates Ids.

Comment: @Harry no, it fetches those who not in subordinates. Probably you didn't see `Except` part of answer

Comment: Thanks a ton Sergey I missed that.

Comment: Serg, Though what you have put is perfectly right but my List isn't simply Employee class it's a viewmodel consisting of other class object(Dept,Finance etc.)  and when I try this it returns all. Any suggestions for this.

Comment: @Harry it's hard to tell what went wrong without seeing your actual code. Make sure you are passing exactly same collection of employee to Except and to GetSubordinates

Comment: Serg, The only difference I have observed is the difference in class I have viewmodel class with multiple object instance and though I could see the list populated only with the subordinate but this fails when use Except it retrieve employeeId as well along with subordinate.